# How can I solve this reference error in my node.js crud application?

Tags: node.js, ejs, node-modules

I don't know how to overcome from this given issue.
**Line no 12**

> > 12|             <% if (products !='') { %>

ReferenceError: C:\Users\Harsh Patel\Downloads\crud-app-main\crud-app-main\views\index.ejs:12 . products are not defined

**So This the code from index.ejs file.**

```
           <%- include('layouts/header') %>
           <div class="container">
           <div class="row my-4">
           <div class="col-lg-12">
           <% if (message) { %>
           <div class="alert alert-dismissible fade show alert-<%= message.type %> " role="alert">
           <button class="btn-close" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> 
          </button>
            <strong><%= message.message  %> </strong>
         </div>
         <% } %>
         <div class="table-responsive">
         <% if (products !='') { %>
            <table class="table table-striped text-center">
                <thead>
                    
    
                    <tr class="table-dark">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <% products.forEach((row, index) => { %>
                        <tr class="align-middle">
                            <td><%= index %> </td>
                            <td><img src="<%= row.image %>" width="100" class="img-thumbnail" /> </td>
                            <td><%= row.name  %> </td>
                            <td><%= row.category %> </td>
                            <td><%= row.price %> </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/edit/<%= row._id  %> " class="text-success"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg mx-1"></i> </a>
                                <a href="/delete/<%= row._id  %>" class="text-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg mx-1"></i> </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                     
                    <% }) %>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         
        <% } else { %>

            <h1 class="text-center text-secondary mt-5">No Products Found!!</h1>
            <% } %> 


    </div>
</div>
```

`
[Reference Error][1]

**This is the code for routers.js in routes folder**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const Products = require('../models/products');
    const multer = require('multer');
    const products = require('../models/products');
    const fs = require('fs');

    // Image Upload
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function(req, file, cb){
       cb(null, './uploads');
     },
     filename: function(req, file, cb){
     cb(null, file.fieldname+"_"+Date.now()+"_"+file.originalname);
   },
});

     var upload = multer({
     storage: storage,

     }) .single('image');

     // Insert product name into database route
     router.post("/add",upload, (req, res) => {
     const product = new Products({
     name: req.body.name,
     category: req.body.category,
     price: req.body.price,
     image: req.file.filename,
  });
     product.save((err)=> {
        if(err){
           res.json({message: err.message, type:"danger"});
        } else {
          req.session.message = {
              type: "success",
              message: "Product added successfully"
          };
             res.redirect("/");
         }
     })
 });



   // Get all products route
   router.get("/",(req, res) => {
     Products.find().exec((err, products)=> {
     if(err){
        res.json({ message: err.message});
     } else {
        res.render("index", {
            title: "Home Page",
            products: products,
           });
       }
   });
});

 router.get("/add",(req, res) => {
      res.render("add_products", {title:"Add Products"});
  });

  // Edit the products routes
  router.get("/edit/:id",(req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Products.findById(id, (err, products) => {
    if(err)
    {
        res.redirect('/');
    }

    else {
        if(products == null){
            res.redirect("/");
        } else {
            res.render("edit_products", {
                title: "Edit Product",
                products : products,
               });
            }
         }
     });   
 });

    //update product routes
    router.post('/update/:id', upload, (req,res)=> {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let new_image = '';

    if(req.file) {
    new_image = req.file.filename;
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync('./uploads/' + req.body.old_image);
    }

    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

} else {
    new_image = req.body.old_image;
}
    Products.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
      name: req.body.name,
      category: req.body.category,
      price: req.body.price,
      image: new_image,

   }, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
          res.json({message: err.message, type: 'danger'});
      } else {
          req.session.message = {
            type:'success',
            message:'Product Updated Successfully'
        };
        res.redirect('/');

         }
     });
 });

   // Delete routes
   router.get('/delete/:id', (req,res)=> {
   let id = req.params.id;
   Products.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err, result) => {
    if(result.image != ''){
        try {
            fs.unlinkSync('./uploads/'+ result.image);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(err);
            
        }
    }
    if(err){
        res.json({message: err.message});
    } else {
        req.session.message = {
            type: 'info',
            message: 'User Deleted'
        };
        res.redirect('/');
      }
   });
});
       module.exports = router;



[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPH9b.png
```

Comment: Well, `products` apparently is not defined inside of the template, so can you please show the code that initiates the template rendering and passes the parameters (and would have to pass `products` as well for it to be defined here)?

Comment: Sure.  I will show the code in which products are defined.